# ANT: Jdbc driver error

Tags: ant

Trying the below code:

```
 <sql
    classpath="postgresql-8.4-701.jdbc3.jar"
    driver="org.database.jdbcDriver"
    url="devtest"
    userid="uid"
    password="pass">

select * from tab where tname = 'GR_DOCUMENT_PRINT_DFV';

 </sql>
```

Getting the below error:

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Program Files\Java\apache-ant-1.8.1\build.xml:62: Class Not Found: JDBC driver
org.database.jdbcDriver could not be loaded

Total time: 1 second
```

Please help.

Now I have updated the code. Add classpath to the previous code. Also add mysql-connector-java-3.0.8-stable-bin.jar and postgresql-8.4-701.jdbc3.jar file to ANT_HOME/lib but still getting the same error.

Comment: What database are you using? Use a driver for that DB

Comment: @JoseK - I am using Oracle 9i Database

Comment: Are you sure that name of your driver is correct? As far I see in examples, it is "org.postgresql.Driver". You can watch inside jar to be sure

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using Oracle, can you try

```
<path id="antclasspath"> 
    <fileset dir="path-to-lib"> 
        <include name="ojdbc14.jar"/> 
    </fileset> 
</path> 


<sql 
    driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" 
    url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@serverip:1521:sid" 
    userid="userid" 
    password="password" 
    print="yes" 
    classpathref="antclasspath"> 
    select * from tab where tname = 'GR_DOCUMENT_PRINT_DFV'; 
</sql>
```

If you still have the same error, run ant with the -v switch. That will direct the sql task to print out the classpath it's using and you can verify.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify class path to your driver

```
<sql classpathref="${classpath.id}" driver="" ...
```

And define your class path

```
<path id="classpath.id">
        <fileset file="..." />
</path>
```

Comment: getting Error`Unresolvable reference ${antclasspath} might be a misuse of property expansion syntax`

Answer (score 1):

does the jar containing `org.database.jdbcDriver` is in the classpath? you probably need to add a classpath attribute

```
<sql
classpath="mysql-connector-java-3.0.8-stable-bin.jar"
driver="org.database.jdbcDriver"
url="devtest"
userid="uid"
password="pass">
```

Comment: I have created a ODBC driver, also added classpath. But still ANT could not found the driver.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <sql
        driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
        url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ENOVIADEV"
        userid="sys"
        password="enoviaV6"
        expandProperties="true"
        classpathref="antclasspath">
        <connectionProperty name="internal_logon" value="SYSDBA"/>          
          <transaction>
            create tablespace ${TablespaceName} datafile '${DatafilePath}/${DatafileNAME}' size 5M REUSE AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT  1280K MAXSIZE UNLIMITED EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL SEGMENT SPACE MANAGEMENT AUTO;
          </transaction>
          <transaction>
          create user ${oracle.dbuser} identified by ${oracle.dbpassword} default tablespace ${TablespaceName} temporary tablespace TEMP;
         </transaction>
         <transaction>
         grant connect, resource, unlimited tablespace to ${oracle.dbuser};
         </transaction>
         <transaction>
         alter user ${Username} default role all;
         </transaction>
    </sql>
```

Comment: Maybe you could add some explanation on why your code solves the issue?