# Cannot find jdbc driver only when builded by Apache Ant

Tags: java, jdbc, ant

I have a problem, when I compile my project by eclipse builder all works fine, but when I do same with Ant i receive error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@1.2.3.4:1521
```

i have

```
ojdbc6.jar
```

in 'lib' and it is in same as 'src', 'bin' etc. folder

```
<project basedir=".">
<target name="jar">

    <mkdir dir="build/jar"/>

    <jar destfile="build/jar/myTool.jar">
        <manifest>              
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="myPackage.application"/>
        </manifest>
        <fileset dir="bin" includes="**/*.class" />
        <zipgroupfileset dir="lib" includes="**/*.jar" />
    </jar>

</target>
</project>
```

in my jar file i can find:

```
oracle\jdbc\driver
```

folder with .class files

and the short code:

```
String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + host + ":" + port;
Properties props = new Properties();
InputStream input = new FileInputStream(getConfigurationFile());
props.load(input);
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,props);
```

when i write:

```
<path id="antclasspath"> 
    <fileset dir="lib"> 
        <include name="ojdbc6.jar"/> 
    </fileset> 
</path> 

<sql 
    driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" 
    url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@1.2.3.4:1521" 
    userid="test" 
    password="test" 
    print="yes" 
    classpathref="antclasspath"> 
    select * from devices; 
</sql>
```

in build.xml file it works and returns right rows, but app still not working when started from .jar file

//edit
excluding external libs from my jar and adding classpath to manifest in ant file resolved my problem

Comment: Probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210722/ant-jdbc-driver-error

Comment: i have found this question, but there is ask statement in ant build file(?), and my is in java class

Comment: How do you start you program?

Comment: in cmd java -jar myTool.jar

Comment: It looks like you are creating a jar that includes all your dependencies, if you have multiple JDBC drivers, then the problem is that you are not merging the `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver` file. This file is used for driver loading since Java 6. It would be better (and easier) to keep your library dependencies out of your own jar, and specify the `Class-Path` attribute with the relative paths of the libraries in the manifest of your own jar.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set your classpath. Try to start yor program with

```
java -cp ojdbc6.jar -jar myTools.jar
```

Please adjust the path to the jar file containing the JDBC driver.

In Ant it works because there you add the jar file to the classpath.

When calling on the CLI you have to provide the classpath.

When using the command line parameter `-jar` you have to provide the classpath via the command line parameter `-cp` (the environment variable `CLASSPATH` will  not work).